# Shift-Enter in tinyMCE (wp 3.3.1) not working

Tags: tinymce, line-breaks

With wordpress version 3.3.1, shift-enter to insert linebreaks in pages and posts is not working anymore.
Has anybody observed this as well? Is there a fix for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me -- have you checked your source code on the published post to see if `<br>` tags are being inserted?

If so, you may want to check your CSS to make sure nothing is over-riding the 
 tags.

One of the biggest culprits can be float: left being applied to the line breaks.

Comment: No, I don't get any `<br>` tags in the source.
It's just a newline in the html source code itself.

Comment: **Clarification**: I don't see `<br>` tags neither in the source code nor in the html editor, but I do see other tags like `<h1>`. When switching between editor modes, I see the `<br>` tags for a fraction of a second, so it looks like some javascript/jquery might be removing those tags? At least they don't make it to the database.

By the way, the same accounts for manually inserting `<br>` tags with the html editor - all get removed.

Comment: make sure this isn't in your theme php file anywhere:  <?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?> -- otherwise it could be your instance of tinyMCE is just not functioning properly... or could be a browser thing.. have you tried in different browsers, or tried a reinstall of WP core?

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried this... but just in case - have you tried disabling all plugins and rechecking?

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem and for me, the following CSS worked:

```
br {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Now just hit enter is working when you edit it in the post.

Comment: Hello & thank you for your answer! It may be beneficial to [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/394016/edit) and add in _where_ the user can add in their custom CSS.